# error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system-mt-1_49.so.1.49.0

Tags: matlab

I'm a beginner MATLAB and C++ user and trying to run some code provided to me. The code

The error I get is:

```
/path/folder: error while loading     
shared libraries: libboost_system-mt-1_49.so.1.49.0: cannot open shared object   
file: No such file or directory
```

The folder exists and the file it's trying to call is in there. I just don't understand what this error is saying with the libboost library?

If I need to provide any of the code that calls the folder, let me know. Not sure how much info to provide.

Comment: Matlab and C++ are very different things. What code are you running? The more info you provide, the better. If your code is not very long, please post it.

Comment: Sorry should've been more specific. It's matlab code that calls some C++ functions. The specific section that isn't working is strictly matlab. The code is pretty long and compiled of several functions which is why I was hoping to get a general idea what libboost refers to and see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have solved the problem. However I see it might still be useful to put some hints here as I see many posts asking for similar questions without being answered.

The solution is to add the library path into your system environment variables. Unfortunately it does not help to set it up outside Matlab (I mean edit the `.bashrc` in Ubuntu etc.).

The correct way is to use the Matlab's functions of reading and setting environment variables: `getenv()` and `setenv().`

Suppose the library file is located at: `/home/username/lib/`, so you will need to write in your Matlab scripts:

`setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH',[getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH') ';/home/username/lib']);`

I am using Linux, however, I think you could solve the problem similarly in other OSs.